# How to write an Financial equation in Java?

Tags: java, math, root, finance

I am currently working on a project which includes creating a program that runs similar to a financial calculator. However I am currently in a fix and would like to get some opinion or gain some knowledge form people within this community. Currently I am using Java gradle and application window and is in the process of actually writing my code. However I am in a fix on how to write the equations and if I should loop the equations in if loops or create different classes so there is not so many loops in one class file. On that note I would also like to note that I an using the Eclipse application for the project too.

The equation I am writing currently is a single cash flow which is FV = PV(1+i)^n and I don't know if I should or am able to write it like this or if I am just over thinking on equation and its totally different from the equation shown. If it is would we need to root the n and if so, how?

I feel like I am over thinking my project and can't see pass what is in front of me. So please past me your wisdom. On another note. Is there a financial application we can or would be able to import or install using github that is not a npm? Also if there is any links that you guy think would help please so kindly link it down below please. For I have restarted my code several times already and feel like I am not getting anywhere. Thank you.

Here is a portion of my code that is not within the gradle application window.

```
package Finance.Calculator.Project;


import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;



public class SimpleFinanceCalc {
    public double FutureValue;
    public double PresentValue;
    public double NumYears;
    public double NumComYear;
    public double Interest;
    public double Growth;
    public double CashFlow;
    public String Operator;


    public SimpleFinanceCalc (double FutureValue, double PresentValue, double NumYears, double NumComYear, double Interest, double Growth, double CashFlow, String Operator){
        this.FutureValue = FutureValue;
        this.PresentValue = PresentValue;
        this.NumYears = NumYears;
        this.NumComYear = NumComYear;
        this.Interest = Interest;
        this.Growth = Growth;
        this.CashFlow = CashFlow;

    }       

    public Double Calculate() {
        if(this.Operator.equals("Single Cash Flow")) {
            return PresentValue * (1 + Interest) Math.sqrt(NumYears)
        }


    }





}
```

Comment: I suggest that you start out by using Java code standards; variable and method names begin with lowercase letters, package names are all lowercase. (You should also use an enum for your `operator`, but that may be later in your course of study.)

Comment: `presentValue * Math.pow(1 + interest, numYears)`

Comment: You probably don't want to use doubles: .1 + .2 will not give you the .3 you're probably expecting. Look into BigDecimal.